# How can I load HTML Code to WebView on Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, webview

i searched on stackoverflow how i can implement my webview on swift to show an html code and already found something.

But it doesnt work. My problem is that I dont get an error. 
My app should start and open a video in the webkit but nothing happens. It just shows a blank page. 
This is my Code. I got a message on the console but dont understand what the problem is.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/0zrSJ6jhAY0\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
}}
```

I also uploaded a screenshot. Maybe I did something wrong with my main.storyboard but i dont think so. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMmAF.png)

Comment: Have you made sure to check the "Outgoing Connections" capability in your target's "Signing and Capabilities" tab?

Comment: The first issue I see, is that you have _two_ webView objects. One is the @IBOutlet the other is created when you call ```let webView```. Try deleting this second one and try again.

Comment: YES thank you very much. I dont know why there were two. Deleted it and it works! Can I click on you helped me or somethings like that? I am new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In UIWebView:-

```
let webView = UIWebView()
webView.loadHTMLString("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>Loading HTML</head><body><p>Hello!`</p></body></html>", baseURL: nil)`
```

As now from April 2020 no app will be allowed with UIWebView. So, we need to use WKWebView for that.

And now here's the code for WKWebView:

```
let webView = WKWebView()
webView.loadHTMLString("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>Loading HTML</head><body><p>Hello!`</p></body></html>", baseURL: nil)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add html tag before and after the body string. Try the following code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        webView.loadHTMLString("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/0zrSJ6jhAY0\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
    }


}
```